# Is there a way to manage machines which are off-domain centrally?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, domain-controller

We have a number of three tier setups here which are mostly Windows Server 2008 boxes.  They tend to consist of 1 web server, 1 application/web services server, 1 db server.  As this is a three tier setup the web server is not on the domain and cannot connect to the domain controller - however the domain controller can resolve the off-domain IP address and authenticate with a local user.

Since we have a number of off-domain boxes used as web servers and SFTP servers I was wondering if there was an easy to manage these servers centrally via GPO or any other method without third-party software?

Comment: What do you mean "manage" them? Manage them in what way? Do you mean remotely connect to them? Do you mean manage their local Group Policy? Do you mean manage them with Server Manager? Etc., etc.

Comment: Effectively all of the above.  Carry out the same action as you would through Server Manager and GPO but not necessarily through those applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply GPO to a non-domain computer, but you can use System Center Config Manager, Intune, or PowerShell Desired State Config to name a few first-party options.